# Integration with respect to product measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

What does $\int f(x,y) d(\mu \otimes \nu)(x,y)$  mean?

Does it mean $\int (\int f(x,y) d\mu(x))d\nu(y)$?

If not, what does it mean?

Comment: If $f\in L^1(\mu\times \nu)$ or is non-negative, and the measures are both $\sigma$-finite, then you can prove the two are equal (Fubini-Tonelli). But the definition is as always; just think of $\mu\times \nu$ as a new measure $\zeta$, and then apply the existing definitions.

Comment: @peek-a-boo im asking if what I wrote is the definition

Comment: and I just answered it is not

Comment: @peek-a-boo could you then please tell me what it means?

Comment: I think you need to re-read my comment above, and then re-read the definitions in a measure-theory book.